# How to make table entries clickable with php and html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to make the following table in this code to be clickable. Basically when the user clicks on it the row elements are going to be send in a PHP file that contains a form to make some updates to the clicked user. The form is going to be prepopulated with the data from the previous table clicked entry,  so that some updates must be done to the specific selection of User.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Table V04</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>

<div class="centerThis">
    <a class="thisButton" href="createUser.html" >Create New User</a>
</div>

<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-table100">
        <div class="wrap-table100">
            <div class="table100 ver1 m-b-110">
                <div class="table100-head">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                        <thead>
                        <tr class="row100 head">
                            <th class="cell100 column1">User Firstname</th>
                            <th class="cell100 column1">User Lastname</th>
                            <th class="cell100 column1">User Email</th>
                            <th class="cell100 column1">User Type</th>

                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="table100-body js-pscroll ps ps--active-y">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                        include '../connection.php';
                        if ($conn->connect_error) {
                            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                        }


                        $sql2 = "SELECT user_Firstname,user_Lastname,user_Email,user_Type FROM User ORDER BY user_Firstname ";
                        $resultForm2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultForm2)) {
                            echo "<tr class='row100 body'>
        <td class='cell100 column1'>" . $row[0] . "</td>
        <td class='cell100 column2'>" . $row[1] . "</td>
        <td class='cell100 column3'>" . $row[2] . "</td>
        <td class='cell100 column4'>" . $row[3] . "</td>
        
    </tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>



<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script src="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.js-pscroll').each(function(){
        var ps = new PerfectScrollbar(this);

        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            ps.update();
        })
    });


</script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt of adding any click event or sending anything to PHP though. Please share what you've tried so far to solve it.

Comment: you can make a table row link -

Comment: `<table> <tr> <a href="#"><td> iam a link</td> </a>  <td>iam not a link</td> </tr> </table>`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i suppose i have to  make like a form inside <tr> so that i can send the entry data via post. But i understand from your comment that i have to write a javascript function in order to caught the click event. I am currently trying to

Comment: You need to ask a specific question about the Javascript you are trying to write.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a HTML Form : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

You will need to change some of your existing HTML code and I would advise to crease a separate PHP file to handle the POST form.

Or you can try and do it with javascript, but I would recommend doing it with and HTML form first to understand basic form management before doing any javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the page on click on the table row, this will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').on('click', '.table tbody tr', function () {
    window.location.href = 'redirect-link-here';
  });
});
```